# Covariance if one variable depends deterministically on time?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, autocorrelation, autoregressive

Suppose we have
$$Y_t = \alpha Y_{t-1}+t$$

Then what is $$Cov(Y_t, Y_{t-1}) = Cov(\alpha Y_{t-1}+t, Y_{t-1}) $$

I’m a bit confused, because on the one hand, the $t$ is not constant, but on the other hand, it is “deterministic”. I’m therefore not sure whether we can treat it as a constant or not. Does it depend on whether we condition on $t$ or not? And what does that mean exactly?

Also, If you would calculate the sample version of that covariance term, what would we expect to find in terms of sample autocorrelation?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\cov}{\text{Cov}}$$\newcommand{\var}{\text{Var}}$$\newcommand{\E}{\text{E}}$This is quite slippery to pin down precisely; I'm going to outline my main thoughts but counterpoints are welcome.

By the linearity of expectation
$$
\cov(\alpha Y_{t-1} + t, Y_{t-1}) = \alpha \var(Y_{t-1}) + \cov(t, Y_{t-1})
$$
so the issue comes down to $\cov(t, Y_{t-1})$. Since this question ultimately is about what is and isn't random, I think we'll need probability spaces so I'll let $(\Omega, \mathscr F, P)$ be my probability space. I'll let $T : \Omega \to \mathbb N$ be the index when thought of as a random variable.

---

I can think of two guiding questions to help determine how the index behaves:

1. as a function of $\omega$ does the index change? I.e. if we sample $\omega \in \Omega$ are we handed a particular $Y_{T(\omega)}(\omega)$, or do we instead still have the collection $\{Y_t(\omega) : t \in \mathcal T\}$?
2. does the index survive the covariance, or do we average over it?

A covariance boils down to expectations which are averages over $\Omega$. If $t$ survives this averaging, i.e. we treat it as fixed/deterministic, that's no different than conditioning on $T=t$, and in this case it will be independent of the random variable in question.

First, a more concrete example. Suppose $\Omega$ is the set of all people and take $X_1(\omega)$ to be $\omega$'s height, and $X_2(\omega)$ to be $\omega$'s age. Thus we have a collection $\{X_t : t\in\{1,2\}\}$. If the index depends on $\omega$ then this would mean that, depending on the person, we are told either their height or their age. If the index does not, then we just have $(X_1(\omega), X_2(\omega))$ for each person. So I could do something like
$$
T(\omega) = \begin{cases}1 & \omega \text{ wears glasses} \\ 2 & \text{o.w.}\end{cases}
$$
and then, when presented with a $\omega$, I return $X_{T(\omega)}(\omega)$, so I give the heights of the bespectacled people and the ages of those without glasses. Then when considering something like
$$
\E (X_T)=\int_{\Omega} X_{T(\omega)}(\omega)\,\text d P(\omega)
$$
I'm averaging this new random variable $X_T$ over all people, which is very different from averaging the heights or ages as in $\E X_1$ and $\E X_2$. Probably for this kind of thing I *don't* want the index to be random, as I'm interested in the sequence $(X_1(\omega), X_2(\omega))$ for each person. Thus the index will not be a function of $\omega$ and so $\cov(X_j, j) = 0$.

---

Next, a more mathy example. Let's say we have a collection of random variables $\{X_j : j \in \mathbb N\}$ and $X_j \sim \mathcal N(j, 1)$. Furthermore let $J \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda)$.

What is $\cov(X_j, j)$? Certainly as $j$ increases so does $\E X_j$ (as this just equals $j$), and similarly $j$ decreasing lowers $\E X_j$. But for a particular $j$, $j$ is just a number so the $\omega$ we observe doesn't change it and therefore $j$ survives the expectation in that $\E X_j = j$. This makes $\cov(X_j, j) = 0$. But instead if we allow the index to vary depending upon which sample space point $\omega$ we are considering, then we end up with something like $X_J$ where $\omega$ both determines the actual value of $X_j$ and also which $j \in \mathbb N$ we end up with. Now, as before,
$$
\E (X_J) = \int_\Omega X_{J(\omega)}(\omega) \,\text dP(\omega)
$$
so $\E X_J$ is just a number and doesn't depend on the index anymore. We've averaged over all the indices.

So for your particular case, I think is more likely you don't want to average over the indices, but both are "legal" things to do. In many cases we've got a collection of RVs $\{Y_t : t \in \mathcal T\}$ and we're interested in the random vector/sequence corresponding to realizing all of them for a given $\omega$, while there are other situations where we have a pool of RVs and the one we get depends on $\omega$. In a time series setting I'm inclined to say you probably don't want to average over the indices, because you probably want to think about each point in time as a thing you look at, rather than rolling a die to decide which time point you see.

---

Regarding the issue of the *sample* covariance between $(Y_1, Y_2,\dots)$ and $(1,2,\dots)$ I don't think this is doing the same thing. Everything up above is about the population covariance, where heree

Finally, I think all of this is different from something like the sample covariance between realizations $(y_1,\dots,y_{10})$ and $(1,\dots,10)$ as these are not draws from the same distribution so this being non-zero doesn't say anything about a particular population covariance $\cov(Y_j,j)$ being zero or not. In my $\{X_j\}$ situation imagine in every case $x_j \approx j$, i.e. each draw was near its mean. Then certainly $\vec x$ and $\vec j$ will be highly correlated, but this is very different from the population correlation between one particular $X_j$ and its index $j$.

Comment: I have two questions: 1. you say "but as a function of ω [t] definitely is constant", but that is only because you set it up that way, right? Couldn't we also set it up such that "we don't know $t$"? In that case,  $t(\omega)$ wouldn't be constant. Therefore, wouldn't there then be a correlation between knowing what $t$ is, and knowing what $Y_{t-1}$ is? if you find out $t$ is high, then $Y_{t-1}$ will also be high. (2) second question: Will there be no correlation between $t$ and $Y_{t-1}$ in the sample? That seems incorrect, simply by plugging it in the sample correlation formula.

Comment: @Programmer2134 I just did a major rewrite. Please let me know your thoughts on this and if it seems to better address your questions